# How to correct and index error in an if statement?

Tags: python

I am a beginner programmer and am, working on this code to practise for my computer science GCSE. 
I am working with this code,

```
import random
file = open("OCR tunes1.csv","r")
temp = file.read()
file.close()

tempList = temp.split("\n")
print(tempList[1])

OCRtunes = []
for item in tempList:
    record = item.split(",")
    OCRtunes.append(record)
print(OCRtunes)
genreOptions = ["pop", "rock", "classical"]
limit = random.choice(genreOptions)
limit = '"' + limit + '"'
print(limit)

increasing = 0
options = []
while True:
    if OCRtunes[increasing][2] == limit:
        options.append(OCRtunes[increasing][0])
        increasing += 1
    else:
        increasing += 1
    if increasing == 20:
       False
print(options)
```

And I get this error.

```
Traceback(most recent call last) :
  File "C:/Users/Jude/Documents/school/computer science/NEA/random playlist genre.py, line 23, in <module>
     if len(OCRtunes[increasing][[2]) == limit:
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

How to remove the error ?

Comment: Please post your code and traceback as text - not as images...

Comment: You should post your code.

Comment: [Don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Although - having a quick look - look at what your `increasing` value is... it appears you want when it's 20 to stop things... and you might want `break` instead of `False`...

Comment: You should use the `csv`-module, you should use `for`-loops.

Comment: This problem could result from a condition you didn't anticipate in the input data. If your input data is small, copy and paste it here.

Answer (score -1):

To process each element of a list, use a `for`-loop:

```
import random
import csv

genre_options = ["pop", "rock", "classical"]

with open("OCRtunes1.csv") as tunes:
    ocr_tunes = list(csv.reader(tunes))

limit = random.choice(genre_options)
options = []
for tune in ocr_tunes:
    if tune[2] == limit:
        options.append(tune[0])
```